# Map with value of list to list oneliner

Tags: collections, kotlin

I'm looking for oneliner or pretty solution for converting

> `Map<Int,List<String>>`

to

> `List<Pair<Int,String>>`

I want to avoid forEach. This question is from pure curiosity if its even possible in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, your edit is the right answer.

Comment: Post your edit as an answer too - it might be useful for others in the future.

Comment: Just one thing need to know: Can we use `.map` instead of `.flatMap` with the same code? While using `.map` kotlin doesn't give an error. If there is a different, want to know.

Comment: The difference is that `flatMap` accepts a function that returns an `Iterable<R>` (`R` being the transformed type), while in `map` the function directly returns `R`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the detail info. :)

Answer (score 1):

The final solution is:

```
.flatMap { (k, v) -> v.map { k to it } }
```